# How do I kill a 5GB init-child zombie process?

Tags: xubuntu, minecraft, zombie

I'm trying not to restart every time I'm done with my game.
I've reported this issue to the DNS community a 2nd time now since I havn't played it for a while since the first time and it's still not fixed.

feel free to have a look:
http://www.dnstechpack.com/forum/index.php?topic=2414.new#new

so with that side getting cleaned up, I'm trying to tackle the other side and kill this annoying process...

Comment: Same as any other zombie process , in this case, size does not matter ;)

Comment: I've tried everything there already, quite a few times, also the whole `5GB` thing was to let people know I can't just leave it... but yea, am I doing something wrong?? I can't kill root w/o killing my compy so...

Comment: post the commands you ran and additional information on the process. You may need to reboot. You may have a bug or memory leak. The zombie may have other children processes. Hard to say from what little you posted.

Comment: killall, sigkill, everything on that page and other pages I'd looked thorugh (this isn't my first case of this, not even my second as it happens whenever I close my game), basically the process doesn't budge... also, the parent is init, not root, excuse me there.

Comment: simply restating you can not kill a process adds little to nothing here. What process ? post the exact commands you ran. post why you think you have a zombie, etc, etc.

Comment: The known (not thought) zombie process is java (obvious by minecraft, and the thread). truthfully, the zombie process is not yet created until I use System Monitor to "kill" the 5GB java process, which immediately marks it as zombie (stopping it's CPU usage). that's the only thing that actually does anything, any other command I've tried either kills the init process or does nothing at all. (I've tried this in both sleeping and zombie states)